# Watson conversation: Regexp as entity

Tags: watson-conversation

At a watson conversation I added a regular expression as entity:

> (e.g. @LimitLiteral :
>   (?i)(\d+(\,|.)\d*\s*[^,.;]*\w*\s*[^,.;]limit)|(limit\s*\d+(.|,)*\d*).

Inside this regexp you can find the constant `limit`. Is it possible to replace this constant `limit` with another entity?

> (e.g. @limit , Limit, maximum , max, not more ..., less)

The advantage is that if possible the regexp can be maintained by adding a new value for the entity `@Limit`

thx

Answer (score 0):

You just can use some condition checking only @LimitLiteral